# How to permanently change (spoof) the MAC address in Kali Linux (Debian)

Tags: kali-linux, mac-address

I use the program 'macchanger' to change MAC address. However, I have to put down an interface (wlan0) and then invoke Macchanger and then bring the interface up again.

I would like to have a way I can store a spoofed MAC address permanently on an interface, so that I don't have to go through the same steps after every reboot.

I would to change the MAC address in a way that withstands a reboot (e.g., editing the /etc/network/interfaces ?)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `/etc/network/interfaces` to configure you interface, there is `hwaddress` option to set its MAC address.

If you use some other configuration mechanism, read its documentation to see what options it has. For example, Network Manager has a special option for MAC spoofing.

Also, there is a script `/etc/rc.local` which is run at system startup. You can run the program that changes MAC address from it.